# Ninject inject dependency from OnApplicationStarted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm using a service from my OnApplicationStarted inside my Global.ascx.cs file. Is there a way to dependency inject the repository from there?

My code:

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    //Need to dependency inject this.
    private IBootStrapService bootService;

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        //Used to set data such as user roles in database on a new app start.
        bootService.InitDatabase();

        base.OnApplicationStarted();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    internal class SiteModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            //I set my bindings here.
            Bind<IBootStrapService>().To<BootStrapService>();
            Bind<IUserRepository>().To<SqlServerUserRepository>()
                .WithConstructorArgument("connectionStringName", "MyDb");
        }
    }
}
```

So how do I get ninject to do DI right inside the app start? As you can see, I setup my bindings in the `SiteModule` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `CreateKernel` method where you would register your modules:

```
protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    return new StandardKernel(
        new INinjectModule[] 
        { 
            new SiteModule()
        }
    );
}
```

This will not automatically inject the `bootService` field though. You could instantiate it like this:

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
    base.OnApplicationStarted();

    //Used to set data such as user roles in database on a new app start.
    var bootService = Kernel.Get<IBootStrapService>();
    bootService.InitDatabase();

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: So after doing just this, the service will be injected before the code in OnApplicationStarted gets executed?

Comment: @Lol coder, no, the `bootService` won't get injected automatically in this case because it is part of the Http Application and Ninject doesn't have control over instantiation of it. You could manually inject it. I will update my post to show an example.